# How do I trap an error when OneDrive image renders file.OpenAsync error

Tags: image, error-handling

In a project I try to give users the option to select images from their personal libraries. Nothing special as such.

This goes perfectly when the user selects the desired image from a local imagelibrary. But when images are selected from OneDrive, an error occurs, and I'm not able to trap the error. The source of the error seems to be in the file.OpenAsync method.

It seems like there may be a relation with the size of the selected image, but I cannot tell, as i'm not able to catch the error.

Here's the codesnippet (it's taken from the XAML image SDK samples in fact)

```
        Dim picker As New FileOpenPicker With {.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail, .SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary}
        'picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp")

        Dim wBitMap as new WritableBitmap(200,200)
        Dim file As StorageFile = Await picker.PickSingleFileAsync()

        ' Ensure a file was selected
        If file IsNot Nothing Then
            Try   ' Set the source of the WriteableBitmap to the image stream
                Using fileStream As IRandomAccessStream = Await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)

                    Await wBitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream)
                    wBitmap.Invalidate()
                    vwImage.Source = wBitmap
                End Using
                Catch e1 As TaskCanceledException
                ' The async action to set the WriteableBitmap's source may be canceled if the user clicks the button repeatedly


            End Try
        End If
```

As you can see, there is a try-catch in place, but nonetheless a non-trapped error pops up, and stepping through, I can detect that it happens in the line

```
Await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)
```

Now my question is: how do I catch this error? Am I right that the line above is the source of the error? And if not so: what is and how to overcome?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of experimenting, I think I found the solutoion.

When a StorgeFile is selected to be used as the source for an image, **it is wise to check the StorageFile.Attributes**.

Files that are selected will carry an Attributes value. In the case of a file from OneDrive, the Attributes value was 544 (the value that you get when combining Archive and LocallyIncomplete. So that file has to be downloaded first, and then it will be available to use.

This is explained here:
[Link to the MSDN documentation on StorageFile.Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileattributes.aspx)